# Is there a way to use the map function in pandas to merge similar rows into their own column?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, jupyter

I need to use the pandas map function to merge two rows (descriptions) into one new row. The new row is Burglary, which includes the ‘Burglary - Residence' and 'Burglary - Non-Residence') rows.

```
df['Burglary'] = df['Burglary - Residence', 'Burglary - Non-Residence''].map()
```

I expect each new row to list the crime and sum the values of each category that was combined.

Current Data:

```
crime                        count         year
Burglary - Residence         21219         2013
Burglary - Non Residence     15946         2013
Bank Robbery                 92            2013
Holdup / Robbery             2907          2013
```

New Data:

```
crime          count      year
Burglary       37165      2013
Robbery        2999       2013
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of your mapping and pass it into `map`.

```
crime_map = {
    'Burglary - Residence': 'Burglary',
    'Burglary - Non Residence': 'Burglary',
    'Bank Robbery': 'Robbery',
    'Holdup / Robbery': 'Robbery'
}

df['crime'] = df.crime.map(crime_map)    
df = df.groupby(['crime', 'year'], as_index=False).sum()

df

Out: 
      crime  year  count
0  Burglary  2013  37165
1   Robbery  2013   2999
```

Comment: This code got me close. The output was each crime sorted by year and count, but it didn't sum up the totals for each category.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
result = df.assign(crime=np.where(df.crime.str.startswith('Burglary'), 'Burglary', df.crime))
print(result.groupby(['crime', 'year'], as_index=False).sum())
```

**Output**

```
              crime  year  count
0      Bank Robbery  2013     92
1          Burglary  2013  37165
2  Holdup / Robbery  2013   2907
```

Note the use of [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) so you can keep your original dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

A more aggregated answer of @Michael_Gardner

```
crime_map = {
    'Burglary - Residence': 'Burglary',
    'Burglary - Non Residence': 'Burglary',
    'Bank Robbery': 'Robbery',
    'Holdup / Robbery': 'Robbery'
}
```

```
df = df.assign(crime=df['crime'].map(crime_map)).groupby(['crime', 'year'], as_index=False).agg({'count': 'sum'})
```

Output

```
      crime  year  count
0  Burglary  2013  37165
1   Robbery  2013   2999
```

Comment: I tried this method and received the following error:  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: make sure your calling map from a `series` object not a `list` object. df['crime'] should be a `series`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
g=df['crime'].str.contains('Burglary')
typ = { True:'Burglary', False:'Robbery'}
df1 = df.groupby([g,'year'])['count'].sum().reset_index()
df1.crime=df1.crime.map(typ)
print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
      crime     year    count
0   Robbery     2013    2999
1   Burglary    2013    37165
```